# testfixturesetup failed in the program

Tags: c#, selenium

I was writing automation using C# Selenium. I wrote this code and the test keeps on failing. what do you think the problem is? chrome opens however it does not google

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4Sel
{
    class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        


        }
        [SetUp]
        public void initialization()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
        [Test]
        public void ExcuteTest()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));



            //perform ops

            element.SendKeys("Execute authomation");
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the error you're getting.
But in any case you forgot to link the path to the driver, meaning:

```
IWebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver(@"YOUR_PATH");
```

Put there your path, for example "D:\Download\chromedriver".